# Useless table not disappearing during normalization process

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-normalization

Let's suggest that there are forests. Each animal lives in exactly one forest. Many wood-wards look after each forest, but each wood-ward looks after exactly one forest.

The schema I'm trying to get is:

- Forest: Forest ID (PK), Forest location;
- Animals: Animal ID (PK), Forest ID (FK), Animal type;
- Wood-wards: Wood-ward ID (PK), Forest ID (FK), Wood-ward name, Date of birth.

1NF:

- Some-useless-table: Forest ID, Forest location,  Animal ID (PK), Animal type, Wood-ward ID (PK), Wood-ward name, Date of birth.

2NF:

- Animals: Animal ID (PK), Forest ID (FK), Animal type, Forest location;
- Wood-wards: Wood-ward ID (PK), Forest ID (FK), Wood-ward name, Date of birth, Forest location;
- Some-useless-table: Animal ID (PK), Wood-ward ID (PK)

3NF:

- Forest: Forest ID (PK), Forest location;
- Animals: Animal ID (PK), Forest ID (FK), Animal type;
- Wood-wards: Wood-ward ID (PK), Forest ID (FK), Wood-ward name, Date of birth;
- Some-useless-table: Animal ID (PK), Wood-ward ID (PK).

When the useless table should disappear? There is no direct relation between animal and wood-ward!

Comment: Which algorithm has been used to find the 3NF? With the usual (synthesis) algorithm only the first three tables are generated.

Comment: I'm using normalization _decomposition_ algorithm.

Comment: Please give a reference to the textbook and algorithm you are using. There are lots of decomposition algorithms. PS Normalizing to a given NF does not in general involve going through lower NFs. PPS Re "There is no direct relation between animal and wood-ward!" So what? (If there had to be a "direct relationship" between every 2 columns, you couldn't decompose.)

Comment: @reaanb Is there are any description of decomposition normalization algorithm which defines that step-by-step normalization is not applicable in such (which?) cases?
Or you mean that in this example the useless table completely disappears during the 4NF step?

Comment: @reaanb Your 1st comment is confused. The 1NF relation can be losslessly decomposed to the three. "Artificial & incorrect" is not helpful; the predicate is the AND of the three components'. There is no need to mention MVDs or 4NF since this decomposition does not involve MVDs that don't correspond to FDs. (There are embedded non-FD MVDs involving {animal}|{ward}, but no non-redundant decomposition involves them.) PS There is a sound & complete axiomatization of FDs + MVDs, so just see some reference on MVDs for it.

Comment: There's nothing special about this case. Your problem is you are not properly decomposing. Give the/a reference you are following. Then show your work. Regarding your 1NF design, it happens that it is adequate for your situations ("forest *fid* is at *flocation* and is home to animal *aid* of type *atype* and is tended by wood-ward *wid* named *wname* born on *wdate*") but in general when we already have separate *predicates* like "forest *fid* is home to animal *aid*" we don't combine them to normalize. There is *no justification for generating* any of the relations you called "useless".

Comment: @philipxy I'm using Wiki as a reference. I'm creating 1NF as a universal relation, then removing part-key dependencies (2NF) and transitive dependencies (3NF) as I've originally posted.

I'm going through the algorithm. I'm asking at what step this useless table would disappear if I program and run normalization algorithm.
If at 4NF, then what would happen between BCNF and 4NF step? Would that table simply disappear and nothing more would happen?

Comment: Wiki is inadequate. You need to find a college/university textbook/slides/course. There are many online. Eg at stanford.edu. I repeat, you haven't made a universal relation properly (you need to have unique attribute names for every predicate/table going into it), you haven't normalized to 2NF properly (you haven't properly redistributed attributes), you shouldn't go through 2NF (it can fail to preserve FDs & it can prevent good higher-NF designs from being found later), etc.